# Instance member 'instance' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, sqflite

i'm making a object in my home class to call databse to perform crud operation using sqflite ,but did'nt understand this error

final dbhelper = Databasehelper.instance;// Instance member 'instance' can't be accessed using static access.

Comment: Can you check if you have added "static" keyword for "instance" variable declaration?

Comment: yes i add static keyword but the error is same

Comment: can you share the code snippet of Databasehelper class how you are declaring "instance" variable and assigning the value to it?

Comment: Maybe you have called the method without creating an instance for the class, so you got this error. If you share the whole code snippet, it would be helpful

Comment: Can you include more details about the question. More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)